# Display the latest images in a directory php

Tags: php

I've had a look but can only find how to display the latest image, or display them all.
 I need to display the 5 latest images.  Thanks

my current code to display 1 image is

```
<?php
$dir = 'images/other';
$base_url = '/images/other';
$newest_mtime = 0;
if ($handle = opendir($dir)) {
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
        if (($file != '.') && ($file != '..')) {
            $mtime = filemtime("$dir/$file");
            if ($mtime > $newest_mtime) {
                $newest_mtime = $mtime;
                $show_file = "$base_url/$file";
            }
        }
    }
}
print '<img src="' .$show_file. '" alt="code">';
?>
```

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: 1) Load the image names into an array. 2) Sort by create time descending. 3)  Show the first 5 indexes of the array. What part of those steps is giving you trouble?

Comment: The latest 5 images in the world?

Comment: @Rizier123 Yes, but not for more than 1 item.

Comment: @kainaw Im new to php so i don't really know what to do.

Comment: @unipartisandev No. From my directory of images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you:

(First I get all files with [`glob()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) and sort them by the last modification with [`filemtime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php) and [`usort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php). After this I get the 5 newest with [`array_slice()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php). And at the end I simply loop through them and print the images)

```
<?php

    $dir = "images/other";

    $files = glob($dir . "/*.*");
    usort($files, function($a, $b){
        return (filemtime($a) < filemtime($b));
    });

    $files = array_slice($files, 0, 5);

    foreach($files as $file)
        echo "<img src='" . $file. "' alt='code'>";

?>
```

Comment: @Arewwwwwwww You're welcome! Have a nice day :D (FYI: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask For next time so that you'll get less downV and more + faster response)